# What is difference between Set and their elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stumble up a thought expressed in Tremblay and Manohar a book on set theory. Following  is an excerpt from Set Theory chapter:

> $$ S = \big\{ a, \{ 1, 2 \}, p, \{q\} \big\}$$
>
> However, it is important to distinguish between the set $\{ q \}$, which is an element of $S$, and the element $q$, which is a member of $\{ q \}$ **but not a member of $S$.**

For the sake of logic, I don't understand that why $q$ which is an element of set $\{ q \}$ is not element of $S$ also?

Here,

$Q$ = Set of all Rational number.

$Z$ = Set of all Integers.

$W$ = Set of all Whole number.

$N$ = Set of all Natural number.

Now, let $$
\{Q\} = \{ \{Z\}, \{W\}, \{N\}\} = \Big\{\{\ldots, -1, 0, 1,\ldots\},\{0, 1,\ldots\},\{1,\ldots\}\Big\}
$$

So, from above quoted logic from book, set of natural number ($N$) is an element of $Q$, but a individual number, say, $1$ is not element of $Q$?

Comment: Because $q\neq\{q\}$, we have that $q$ is not an element of $S$. Also, there is something very wrong with your construction of the rational numbers

Comment: What is the difference between Integers and Whole numbers?

Comment: Where did the sentence "Now, let $\{Q\} = \{\{Z\},\{W\}\{N\}\}$ come from?  That makes no sense and is invalid.  $\{Q\} \ne  \{\{Z\},\{W\}\{N\}\}$ and you can't "let" it be equal any more than you can let $100$ be prime.

Comment: @Vsotvep presumably whole numbers are non-negative and include $0$.....

Comment: Then what's the difference between whole numbers and natural numbers?

Comment: If you wrote $Q = \mathbb Z \cup \mathbb N$, then it would equal $\{\ldots -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, which contains the individual number $1$.  Also, $\mathbb Q$ contains additional elements you do not cover.

Comment: Because $q \ne \{q\}$ and the elements within elements that are sets are not elements of the set.  I have a phone book full of people in my living room.  Mary smith is in my phone book; the phone book is in my living room.  But Mary smith is not in my living room.

Comment: @Vsotvep natural numbers do not include $0$.  But that isn't relevant to the question and not important.

Comment: @fleablood The point I'm trying to make to the OP, is that [whole numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) generally are the same as either integers or as natural numbers. Also, the question if $0$ a natural number is a rather trivial matter of style.

Comment: @Vsotvep Who cares? The OP obviously didn't make up the example and nitpicking that three classifications of integers, whole number, natural numbers, is redundant only serves to derail the discussion.   And putting this as burden that the OP must clear up before we'll even consider their legitimate question is unfair.  It'd be more fruitful to direct this at the author of the question; not the OP.

Comment: @fleablood First of all, who cares if you define the things you use properly: just about every mathematician. That's what mathematics is about, being precise and nitpicking about the things you work with. Second of all, it *is* a burden to have to think about these things, but that's exactly the kind of thing one should learn when learning mathematics. Thirdly, my question was indeed directed towards the author of the question, who is incidentally the O(riginal)P(oster) of the question, and not towards you, so I'm not sure why you answered it instead.

Comment: @Vsotvep The point is that the distinction between the three classes of numbers (whole, natural, and integer) is a minor technical detail which is (1) irrelevant to this question and (2) made clear by the final displayed equation (the whole numbers are $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$, the nonnegative integers; the natural numbers are $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, the positive integers).  The more pressing issues are that (a) the asker does not seem to understand the distinction between $x$ and $\{x\}$, and (b) the example given doesn't make sense.  These are much more substantive problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this analogy.

If you have a bag containing a box of chocolates, then the bag contains one item (the box). The bag does not contain the individual chocolates; you can't take a chocolate out of the bag--you can only take the single box out of the bag.

The individual chocolates are like $q$. The box of chocolates is like $\{q\}$ (only one chocolate, so sad!). The bag containing the box of chocolates is like $S$, which is $\{\{q\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$S = \{a, \{1,2\}, p, \{q\}\}$.

The set $S$ has four elements.  There are four thing in  $S$.  They are:

1) $a$.

2) A set containing $1$ and $2$.  It is the *set* that is an element of $S$; not the individual numbers.

3) $p$

4) A set containing $q$.

Those are the only $4$ things $S$.

Some of the things in $S$ have further things inside of *them*.  But those things inside things are *not* inside $S$. They are not allowed to crawl out of their packages and be in $S$.

$1$ is not an element of $S$.  It is *not* one of the four things.  It is *in* one of the four things but it is *not* one of the four things. $q$ is not an element of $S$.  It is not one of the four things either.